# Google Tag Manager Button

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a button which has padding however it is wrapped in a span tag. I'm using `Click - All Elements` as a trigger in Google Tag Manager.

```
<button id="gtm-id" class="gtm-class"><span>Click here</span></button>
```

So if I now click the span instead of the button element in the DOM, the span is `"this"` it's the element being clicked, so now it doesn't get the id="gtm-id" because it's not the element being clicked.

How can I get Google Tag Manager to bubble up and get the data from it's wrapping parent element?

Answer (score 3):

I set `pointer-events:none` on my span effectively hiding this from a click event to expose the `<button>` wrapping layer underneath

Comment: After a lot of investigation, this seems to be a great solution. I'm unsure why it's not recommended more often. Note this works with all elements, including if you have an svg icon in the button.